# WPF app early TypeInitializationException catch

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

My team distributes a WPF application to more than a thousand machines. 99.9% of the time the app works as expected, however, once in a while we get an exception from C++. Usually it is a very early-on exception. Obviously, we don't have access to Visual Studio and tools (however, I could probably dist some standalone tool), debugging, admin rights, etc. In such cases I feel totally helpless resorting to guessing. Windows EventLog is not of much help. 
Main() method is in generated code App.g.i.cs, and is quite standard, I imagine. 
How do I insert a try/catch around it? Would it even give any clues? The main objective is, obviously, to eliminate or reduce guessing.

```
public static void Main() {
MyProgram.App app = new MyProgram.App();
app.InitializeComponent();
app.Run();
```

}

Exception from Windows Event log is this:

```
Application: MyProgram.EXE
```

Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException 
Stack: 
   at MyProgram.App.Main()

Faulting application name: MyProgram.EXE, version: 2012.9.4.0, time stamp: 0x53628262 
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1677 
Exception code: 0xe0434352 
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d 
Faulting process id: 0x1b18 
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf8f6f7c57dd1d 
Faulting application path: c:\WritableFolder\MyProgram.EXE 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 
Report Id: baa30260-fb62-11e3-b7d9-a0d3c10c1ecc

Thank you (this is not part of the event log message)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you might be able to trap the exception in the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnAppDomainUnhandledException;

        // ... existing code
    }


    private void OnAppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Log exception in more detail (note e.IsTerminating for interest)
    }
```

When this event fires there's no ability to "handle it" any more, but it should give you the opportunity to log the exception in more detail since I'd guess that an InnerException is being hidden there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I am missing something...  Main() is in generated code file and will be overwritten. A part of the question is how I can place any code there. If I could then I'd guess a simple try-catch would suffice. On the other hand, the place where I can add the handler is too late in the initialization...

Comment: This means you should have a App.xaml.cs where you can override `OnStartUp`. Perhaps subscribe to the event there before calling `base.OnStartup()`?

Comment: I agree with @Stuart, the App class constructor would be the earliest place to subscribe to that event.

Answer (score 0):

(apologies not enough rep to comment on Andre's answer yet)

In your App.xaml.cs add the UnhandledException handler to the constructor

```
public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnAppDomainUnhandledException;
```

and method to log exception

```
private void OnAppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Log exception in more detail (note e.IsTerminating for interest)
}
```

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks, yes - I just added a similar comment myself.